# Nginx wont let me download .zip files from my web server

Tags: php, nginx, https

I'm trying to browse to and download a .zip file on my web server (https://mywebsite.com/portfolio/downloads/MyFile.zip) but instead, it returns the HTML content of /var/www/html/index.php ? It's not downloading the file.

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default contents:**

```
server
{
    # GENERAL CONFIGS

    server_name MYWEBSITE.com;

    location ^~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
            alias /var/www/html/.well-known/;
    }

    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;

}


server {
    # SSL configuration

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/MYWEBSITE.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/MYWEBSITE.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    server_name MYWEBSITE.com;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location /projectdev/minigames/design.html {
    deny all;
    }

# ROOT Location
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }


    location /blog {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php;
    }

    location /forum {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /forum/public/index.php;
    }

    #location @rewrites {
    #    if (!-e $request_filename)
    #{
    #    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
    #    break;
    #}
    #}

    location = /favicon.ico {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

#    location ~ /\. {
#        access_log off;
#        log_not_found off;
#        deny all;
#    }

                location ^~ /.well-known {
                        allow all;
                        alias /var/www/html/.well-known/;
                }

    # PHP Configs
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

    location ~ \.php {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO            $fastcgi_path_info;
    #fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED      $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;

                fastcgi_param    HTTPS                                                          on;

    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING         $query_string;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD       $request_method;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE         $content_type;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH       $content_length;

    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME          $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME      $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI          $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI         $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT        $document_root;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL      $server_protocol;

    fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE      nginx;

    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR          $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT          $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR          $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT          $server_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME          $server_name;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

What's wrong in my nginx configuration that isn't allowing my web server to download .zip files when you browse to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the line causing the redirection:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

It is trying to serve the file, failing and then redirecting to "/index.php?"

I am using on my server the following and it's working fine:

```
location / {
            ## try_files $uri @rewrite;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            autoindex on;
    }
```

Don't forget to reload nginx after you make your changes